# Trying to delete Row from table using react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So what I have done here is created a table with 5 ByDefault rows for that aI created a array with 5 elements and mapped over it and I got the rows. After that I created an input field in which user can enter the number of extra rows they want, using the "increaseRow" function and the user input I push Elements in the array so that i can get that number of rows and got it as well. But when I Keep the By Default rows as it is and some new rows e.g 5 rows and try to DELETE all 10 rows it creates problem

All I want is the rows should get DELETED.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
  const row1 = [];
  const [row, setRow] = useState();
  const [NewRow, setNewRow] = useState([1,2,3,4,5]);
  const [allRowsAdded, updateAllRows] = useState(0);

  const addRow = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRow(e.target.value);
  };

  const increaseRow = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(row); i++) {
      row1[i] = allRowsAdded + i;
    }
    updateAllRows((allRowsAdded) => allRowsAdded + parseInt(row));
    setNewRow([...NewRow, ...row1]);

  };

  const deleteRow = (id) => {
    const updatedRows = [...NewRow].filter((rowId) => {
      return rowId !== id;
    });
    setNewRow(updatedRows);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type="text" onChange={addRow} placeholder="Enter Number Of Row's" /><br />
        </form>
        <button onClick={increaseRow}> Add </button>


      </div>
      <div className="container">
        <form >
          <Table striped bordered hover responsive variant="light">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> No. </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Injection Speed </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Fill Time </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Peak Inj Press </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Viscocity </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Shear Rate </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> AbsoluteDropViscocity </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> %DropViscocity </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Action </h6>{" "}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className="grid_style">
              {NewRow.map((rowId) => {
              return (
                <tr key={rowId}>
                  <td> {rowId} </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" readOnly />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" readOnly />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" readOnly />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" readOnly />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <i
                      className="fa fa-trash viscocity_icons"
                      onClick={() => deleteRow(rowId)}
                    >
                    </i>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
         
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-allen-iun6b?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a `logical error (rowId clashes)` that you are doing.

```
const increaseRow = () => {
  for(let i=0; i < row; i++){
    row1[i] = i;
  }
  setNewRow([...NewRow, ...row1]);
}
```

Here when u are assigning value to a row, you are taking index as id for that row. According to which, this is happening with rowId
[image]

and on removing a row and filtering based on rowId, for eg: id=1

```
const deleteRow = (id) => {
   const updatedRows = NewRow.filter((rowId) => {
       return rowId!== id;
   })
   setNewRow(updatedRows)
}
```

2 rows are removed with rowId=1, ie. at serial number 1 and 6.

---

#### Solution

You can correct this by adding anything for `unique Keys`, like uuid. Here I have used an extra state variable `const [allRowsAdded, updateAllRows] = useState(0);` which stores the total number of rows added from now and add the rowIds next to the addedRows.

```
const increaseRow = () => {
   for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(row); i++) {
      row1[i] = allRowsAdded + i;
   }
   updateAllRows((allRowsAdded) => allRowsAdded + parseInt(row));
   setNewRow([...NewRow, ...row1]);
};
```

Now, rowIds becomes

[image]

And there will be no rowId clashes.

Code Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-snowflake-26v1o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Sir....Still Facing Same problem some are getting deleted some are not.....@HimanshuSingh

Comment: If i generate 5 rows, then 0,1,2 are getting deleted, 3,4 are not.....I tried console.log(updatedRows) to checl

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-snowflake-26v1o?file=/src/App.js

Check this

Comment: Thank You so much @HimanshuSingh Great Help

Comment: There is a change in the table now bydefault 5 rows are should be there....can you help me out ? @HimanshuSingh

Comment: Refer `sandbox link` . Initialize `NewRow` with `[...Array(5)]`. `const [NewRow, setNewRow] = useState([...Array(5)]);`

Comment: @HimanshuSingh......I have Done that.....Bydefault rows are not the problem.....Can you read the problem statement again I have made Edits and added a sandbox Link too, By Keeping the bydefault rows as it is if I new rows e.g 5 then all 10 rows should get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

here is by my understanding will work,

```
  const deleteRow = (id) => {
    const updatedRows = NewRow.filter((index) => {
        return index !== id;
    })
    setNewRow(updatedRows)
}
```

change your html code,

```
<td> <i className="fa fa-trash viscocity_icons" onClick={() => deleteRow(index)}></i> </td>
```

i dont know about datastructure or json of array,

```
  const deleteRow = (id) => {
    const updatedRows = NewRow.filter((e) => {
        return e.id !== id;
    })
    setNewRow(updatedRows)
  }
```

Comment: can you add it on codesandbox, someone will surely fix this